# MVC3 on textbox change update a field or enable Save button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, onchange

I have a C#.Net MVCV3 web app.  There is a requirement that, when a user changes the text in a text box and tabs out of the text box, the app needs to update either modify the title of the page by appending a "*" to indicate the page is in need of saving.....OR...enable the Save button to indicate the page needs to be Saved.  I don't know how to do this in the client code without submitting the form.  Any ideas?

Editting to reflect summary of comments with 3nigma.  The keyup and change functions needed to be added to either the Window.Load event or the document.ready event:

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#Description").keyup(function (e) {
            $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
            document.title = document.title + "*";

        });
    });
```

OR

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Description").keyup(function (e) {
            $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
            document.title = document.title + "*";

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery for that, on document ready disable the submit button

```
$(function(){
$("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

bind a change event to the fields that the user can change like `textbox`

```
$("#TextBoxID").change(function(){    
//enable the submit button here
$("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

or append a `*` like

```
$("<span/>",{text:"*"}).appendTo("#TextBoxID");
```

Comment: The OP asked for the title of the page to have an `*` added. Is this possible?

Comment: @3nigma....thanks!  One question...in the functin disabling the submit button.  Do i have to give the function the Id or Name of the button?

Comment: @Valamas i didnt read the question carefully but there is an `OR` i guess i answered that

Comment: @MikeTWebb if you **dont** have multiple `input` with `type="submit"` you dont have to do it but if the submit button has an id you can simply select it by `id` its your choice like `$("#SubmitID")`

Comment: @3nigma...I got the disable to work but not the change event. Here's what the TextArea looks like:  <textarea Id="theDescirption" Name="theDescription" class="celltext2" cols="40" data-val="true" data-val-required="Description is required." id="Description" name="Description" rows="4">
</textarea>
and the jQuery:          $("#theDescirption").change(function () {
            //enable the submit button here
            $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
        });

Comment: @MikeTWebb the `change` should be working try clicking out side the text area after you have changed the value or try the `keyup` event

Comment: @3....ok...also, I use the  @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Description) to craete the textarea.  Could this affect the behavior?

Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description,
                    new
                    {
                        rows = 4,
                        cols = 40,
                        @class = "celltext2"
                    })

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5481/discussion-between-miketwebb-and-3nigma)

Comment: @MikeTWebb `@Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Description)` will generate the html something like `<textarea name="Model.Description"` try instead `@Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Description,new{@id="theDescription"})` to give an id to your textarea

Comment: @3....yep, tried that.  It had 2 id's then, one for "Description" and one for "theDescription"

Comment: i didnt get you what do you mean by 2 ids you should not have identical ids

Comment: sorry...one id was "Id" the other"id"....but I fixed that am not getting the functions to fire.  I put an alert in the functions and those didn't who either.  Do I need something sepcial in the  <script language="javascript">
tag?

Comment: @3...yeah, that looks right.  I copied it into my code and no go.  Mayb I'm not including the right jQuery js files?

Comment: hey...I figured it out.  I did a view source on your code and found this:         $(window).load(function () {
            $("textarea").keyup(function (e) {
                $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");

            });
        });

Comment: This worked...the function needed to be added to the window.load event

Comment: @MikeTWebb you are welcome, you can also do it like `$(document).ready(function(){//the disable code here});`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title of the page using the following.
Adapt something like the following into any change functions.

```
<script language="javascript">
document.title = document.title + "*";
</script>
```